# Product promotion countdown

Tags: php, e-commerce, countdown, opencart

I'm new to OpenCart and I'm trying to build an ecommerce website. I want to show the time left for my promotions and I don't know how. When I have a product with a promotion I want to show the time left to the ending of it ("countdown: 3 hours and 23 minutes").

I've seen some examples (http://www.opencartaustralia.com/recycle/) but the problem is that when the time is over the product becomes unavailable. I just want the product to revert to the old price.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's any good, but here's somebody selling a countdown bundle for opencart for 38 USD: [OpenCart Countdown Timer Bundle](http://www.kedgegroup.com/store/OpenCart_Countdown_Timer_Bundle_V1_2).

Comment: the problem is when the time is over the product stays unavailable. I want the product remain available but with the old price.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: If you won't get a response here, try asking at the opencart community forums: http://www.opencart.com/forum/. They seem to be fairly responsive.